# Centering vertical text within merged rows

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

please help me to centre the word 'Design' in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%space between rows
\label{table:designSP}
\caption{Sub-processes within Urban Design}

  \begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    \toprule
     & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\textbf{Sub-processes}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}|}{\textbf{Description}}  \\ \hline
     \multirow{4}{*}{\rot {Design}}
     & \textbf{Establishing a \newline Vision}     &  Generating a shared vision for positive change through an intentional design process that integrates the aspirations of multiple stakeholders. \\
     & \textbf{Making \newline Trade-offs}                  &   As the shared vision moves through the design and implementation phases, the interests of stakeholders can be competing and contradictory, requiring multiple trade-offs to be made. How these trade-offs are managed is ultimately embodied within the final built outcome. \\
     & text                      &      text                                            \\ 
     & text & text \\ \hline
     \multirow{4}{*}{\rot {Design}}
     & text                      &                           &                           &                           &                           \\
     & text                      &                           &                           &                           &                           \\
     & text                      &                           &                           &                           &                           \\ \hline
     
     
  \end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Output
[image: Output]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first `multirow` cell in span about 8 text lines, consequently it should be defined as `\multirow{8}{*}{\rot{Design}}`. Correcting this, "Design" will move approximately to vertical center of the cell. It position you can fine tuned by option added before cell contents. for example:

  ```
  \multirow{8}{*}[1ex]{\rot{Design}}
  ```

  for move cell's content for 1 ex higher.
- off-topic: you define `p` type of columns, so it is superfluous to use `\multicolumn` cels with the same type of column:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,
                booktabs,
                multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%space between rows
    \label{table:designSP}
    \caption{Sub-processes within Urban Design}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\raggedright\bfseries}p{3cm} p{10cm}|}
        \hline
         & Sub-processes
            & \textbf{Description}      \\
        \hline
    \multirow{8}{*}{\rot{Design}}
         & Establishing a Vision
            &  Generating a shared vision for positive change through an intentional design process that integrates the aspirations of multiple stakeholders. \\
         & Making  Trade-offs
            &   As the shared vision moves through the design and implementation phases, the interests of stakeholders can be competing and contradictory, requiring multiple trade-offs to be made. How these trade-offs are managed is ultimately embodied within the final built outcome. \\
         & text     &   text    \\
         & text     &   text    \\
         \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\rot{Design}}
         & text     &   text    \\
         & text     &   text    \\
         & text     &   text    \\
         & text     &   text    \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Zarko.

Comment: @Svendson, you are welcome. If answer solve your problem, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at the top left side of answer). Happy TeX-ing!